# Django how to best address unicode errors

Tags: django, unicode

I have a view along the lines of:

```
def export(request, exportCSV):
    if exportCSV:
    ...
    # get a list of results named list
    ...
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)

    writer.writerow(['firstfield', 'secondfield', ... ,])
    for item in list:
        writer.writerow([item.firstfield, item.secondfield, ... ,])
    return response
```

The problem is that some of the fields contain Spanish text and such fields raise the following error:

```
    'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Now, if I append `.encode('utf8)` to offending fields, all is well:

```
...
for item in list:
    writer.writerow([item.firstfield.encode('utf8'), item.secondfield.encode('utf8'), ... ,])
```

However, appending this to each field clearly violates DRY. Additionally, not every field accepts this encoding. If I append to some fields I generate this error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

or:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

So how can I best deal with this first error whilst ensuring fields don't generate the second  type of errors? Should I be even dealing with this at the view level or can it be taken care of in the models?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples, there is an example of a unicode_csv_reader. You could also catch the UnicodeDecodeError(or w/e error you are seeing) and encode the text fields appropriatly.

Comment: hmm. I tried with the UnicodeWriter class but I still encounter the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have look at `smart_str` and the other conversion functions here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#conversion-functions

To keep it DRY you could use it like this...

```
my_fields = ['firstfield', 'secondfield', 'thirdfield']

for item in list:
    writer.writerow([smart_str(getattr(item, x)) for x in my_fields])
```

**EDIT** FK relationships

Try something like (untested) ...

```
def get_field(obj, field):
    value = obj

    for f in field.split('.'):
        value = getattr(value, f)

    return value

my_fields = ['firstfield.firstsubfield', 'secondfield.sub.subsub', 'thirdfield']

for item in list:
    writer.writerow([smart_str(get_field(item, x)) for x in my_fields])
```

The `get_field` method should work with any relationship depth.

Comment: This looks promising. However, my filed lookups involve multiple joins. How do I use `getattr` on something like `item.firstfield.firstsubfield`?

Comment: Great! Thankyou. As in my case the `firstfield` is common to all queries, I can actually get away with: `writer.writerow([smart_str(get_field(firstfield, x)) for x in fields_list])`. And `smart_str` is definitely the way to deal with all fields be they spanish characters, None or Int.

Answer (score 0):

So, for completeness. Here is my working code:

```
# get_field function
def get_field(obj, field):
    value = obj
    for f in field.split('.'):
        value = getattr(value, f)
    return value

def csv(request, exportCSV)
    ...
    if exportCSV:
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.csv'
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        # write headings                
        writer.writerow([
            'Verbose Heading FirstField',
            'Verbose Heading ScondField',
        ]) 
        # create list of fields as objects
        fields_list = [
            'subfield1.subsubfield1.subsubsubfield1',
            'subfield1.subfield2',  
        ]
        for item in results_list:
            writer.writerow([smart_str(get_field(item, x)) for x in fields_list])
```